# Azure Mobile Apps - Request user profile information

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

How do you make a request to Google to get a user's profile information with the returned tokens from Azure Mobile Apps?  Specifically I am using the iOS Microsoft SDK in Objective-C.

1. I found this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/10/24/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services/) but it looks to be referencing old information based on the date and the response that was returned.
2. I also tried calling `/.auth/me` as a `GET` request, but that returned `Cannot GET /api/.auth/me`

Comment: Regarding #2, it looks like the client you're using is prepending "/api" to the cal to /.auth/me, which is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an HTTP request to `/.auth/me`, but **without** using the custom API support that's in the iOS SDK. In other words, use `NSURLRequest` directly, and not `MSClient.invokeAPI`. Your call needs to be authenticated, so put the token from `client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken` in the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header.

We have an open feature request to add a method to the client SDKs to make this easier: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/issues/30.

And, you're right that your article was referencing information on Azure Mobile Services, which behaves completely differently when it comes to authentication.

Comment: what information do I send with the GET request and how?  It seems like it needs a header value.

Comment: Attach the token from client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header.